# ¿Cómo guardar arrays dentro de arrays en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito guardar varios array de forma dinámica dentro de un array base, y necesito que cada posición tenga un string en vez de un indice, ejemplo:

Lo siguiente sería un array llamado `Array1` en `ArrayBase` con `Hola` como primer elemento:

```
ArrayBase[Array1][0]="Hola";
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Las buenas preguntas en este sitio incluyen una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado, usualmente mencionan lo que han intentado y señalan claramente dónde se quedaron "atorados" o un problema específico. Por favor edita tu pregunta para hacerla una buena pregunta. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Has pensado en la idea de usar un array multidimensional dinámico? Puedes leer mucho más aquí https://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/632.php

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lo que estás planteando tiene un problema de concepto, `Array1` es un array, pero se está poniendo en un lugar donde es la posición del elemento del array. Es decir, no puede ser un array y una posición al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer de la manera que quieres hacerlo no tiene mucho sentido, básicamente por concepto tal y como dice @ArtEze
Podrías probar con un Map guardando como clave el `Array1` y como valor un array. Puedes leer más sobre el Map en Javascript [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descubri como podia hacerlo (lo posteo por si alguien lo llegara a necesitar) en javascript hay unas cosas llamadas diccionarios (que en realidad son colecciones de objetos), y se implementan de la siguiente manera:

```
var conjuntos= {};

conjuntos[GuardarNombreConjunto]=PalabrasAGuardar;//donde GuardarNombreConjunto es una variable String que le da cierto nombre asociativo al array, y PalabrasAGuardar es un array de strings (en mi caso) pero en realidad puede ser cualquier cosa
```

Comment: Puedes marcar tu respuesta como correcta, si ya llegaste a una solución.

Comment: No me deja, me aparece que hasta mañana